# Какие условные конструкции использовать?

Tags: c#

Всем привет! Есть такая задача, которую я не знаю как решить, для начала посмотрите на метод:

```
public void GetFromVK(ReadOnlyCollection<Post> wall) 
{
    foreach (var post in wall)
    {
        string text = post.Text;

        var photo = post.Attachment.Instance as Photo;

        if (photo == null)
            continue;

        string photoUrl = photo.Photo604.AbsoluteUri;
    }
}
```

В `post` я получаю фото и текст, мне нужно записать их в текстовый файл, все бы ничего, но если фото нет, то я получаю ошибку что отсутствует ссылка на объект и программа прекращает свое выполнение, выход я нашел создав условие  `if (photo == null)continue;`.Но как в этом случаи мне записать в файл, что фотки нет? В моем случаи идет обрыв цикла.

Как писать в файл, если нет текста пишем "нет текста", если нет фотки, то "нет фотки"?
Спасибо!
Попробовал так:

```
public void PhotoGetFromVK(ReadOnlyCollection<Post> wall) 
{
    foreach (var post in wall)
    {
        string text = post.Text + Environment.NewLine;
        File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Shato\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication23\WindowsFormsApplication23\1.txt",text );

        var photo = post.Attachment.Instance as Photo;

        if (photo == null)
        {
            string photoNotFound = @"Photo not found" + Environment.NewLine; 

            File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Shato\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication23\WindowsFormsApplication23\1.txt", photoNotFound);

            continue;
        }

        string photoUrl = photo.Photo604.AbsoluteUri + Environment.NewLine;
        File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Shato\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication23\WindowsFormsApplication23\1.txt", photoUrl);
    }
}
```

Но записывается только одна запись, но мне кажется вообще написано бредово).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (photo == null)
{
    string photoNotFound = @"Photo not found";
    continue;
}
```

По моему ответ очевиден...

**UPD** Нет, не так как вы сделали

```
public void PhotoGetFromVK(ReadOnlyCollection<Post> wall) 
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var post in wall)
    {
        result.Append(post.Text + Environment.NewLine);

        var photo = post.Attachment.Instance as Photo;
        if (photo == null)
        {
            resut.Append(@"Photo not found" + Environment.NewLine); 
        }
        else
        {
            result.Append(photo.Photo604.AbsoluteUri + Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }

    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(
        @"C:\Users\Shato\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication23\WindowsFormsApplication23\1.txt",
        result.ToString()
        );
}
```

А вот ту длинную страшную строку

```
@"C:\Users\Shato\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication23\WindowsFormsApplication23\1.txt"
```

, я бы заменил на

```
Application.StartupPath + @"1.txt"
```

Comment: А зачем собачка в перед строкой?

Comment: Привычка. "Преимущество точных строк заключается в том, что escape-последовательности не обрабатывается, благодаря чему можно удобно написать, например, полное имя и путь файла" (с) msdn

Comment: Спасибо. А где мне писать  `System.IO.File.WriteAllText` ? И как мне исполосовать photoNotFound? Предложный вами вариант, я вроде как пробовал, после `continue` идет обрыв цикла и как я запишу в файл?

Comment: Я бы в вашем случае в начале функции сделал переменную StringBuilder result (https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), а переменные string заменил на result.Append(...). В файл же я бы писал в самом конце после result.ToString().

Comment: @Mirdin: Чтобы немного упростить код, воспользуйтесь `StringBuilder.AppenLine`.

Comment: @Mirdin: А вот писать в `Application.StartupPath + @"1.txt"` я бы очень не рекомендовал. В реальной жизни приложение будет лежать в защищённом от записи `Program Files`. Писать надо в `%APPDATA%\App name`.

Comment: @VladD, я исхожу из того, что приведенный в вопросе код, имеет какой либо смысл (например в рамках учебного задания, или что нибудь другое...) поэтому старюсь изменять его как можно меньше. Что касается записи в файл, то по уму, следовало вернуть из функции строку, а сохранять ее уже где то отдельно, но опять таки, возможно, это имеет какой то смысл.

Comment: @Mirdin: Это да, тут вы правы.

Answer (score 4):

```
/// <summary>
/// Записывает в текстовый файл ссылки на фотографии прикрепленные к сообщениям на стене
/// 
/// Если к сообщению не была прикреплена фотография, то 
/// в файл будет записана строка "Photo not found"
/// </summary>
/// <param name="wall">Сообщения со стены</param>
/// <param name="outputFile">Файл для записи ссылок фотографий</param>
public void PhotoGetFromVK(IEnumerable<Post> wall, string outputFile)
{
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(outputFile))
    {
        foreach (var post in wall)
        {
            var attachmentInstance = post.Attachment.Instance;

            if (attachmentInstance is Photo)
            {
                var photo = (Photo)attachmentInstance;
                writer.WriteLine(photo.Photo604.AbsoluteUri);
            }
            else
            {
                writer.WriteLine("Photo not found");
            }
        }
    }
}
```